# Strange behaviour on Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, google-visualization

I have a Chart which has two view, first view: 6 months, and second: 12 months. All the two views should have the same data, but actually they don't.

First of all, let me show you the print screen I took:

Obs.: It's in portuguese, so I'll put some subtitles at end.

So, this is the 12 months chart:

[image]

Now let's see the 6 month chart. Here it is:

[image]

As you can clearly see, the three last months in the 6 months chart is not displayed anymore as the 12.

Let me show you the code that mount all these things.
The responsible code is this:

```
var someEvolutionChart = {};

someEvolutionChart.container = document.getElementById('chart-div');

someEvolutionChart.setupChartData = function (objects) {
    var items = [['Day', 'Visits', 'Received Calls']];
    if(objects['objects'].length < 1) {
        items.push(['Some text', 0, 0]);
        return items;
    }

    $.each(objects['objects'], function(index, val) {
        items.push([val.date, val.visited, val.calls]);
    });

    return items;
};

someEvolutionChart.getMaxValue = function (objects) {
    var max_value = 0;

    $.each(objects['objects'], function(index, val) {
        max_value = Math.max(max_value, val.visited, val.calls);
    });

    return max_value;
};

someEvolutionChart.setVAxisMax = function(value, options) {
  options['vAxis']['maxValue'] = findMaxAxisValue(value, 0, false);
};

/* The interval is the quantity of months, 6 and 12, but it starts from 0 to 5 and 0 to 11. */
function loadsomeEvolutionChart(interval){
    var days = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var months = days * 30;

    var initial_date = new Date();
    initial_date = new Date(initial_date - (months * interval));
    var period = initial_date.getFullYear() + "-" + (initial_date.getMonth() + 1);

    var spinner = new Spinner({
        'top': '100'
    }).spin(someEvolutionChart.container);

    var url = '/api/v1/.../?format=json&period__gte=' + period;

    $.getJSON(url, someEvolutionChart.callback);
}

someEvolutionChart.callback = function (objects) {
    var items = someEvolutionChart.setupChartData(objects);
    var max_value = someEvolutionChart.getMaxValue(objects);

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(items);

    var options = {
        pointSize: 5,
        height: 300,
        chartArea: { width: "100%", left: 40, top: 20 },
        legend: { position: "bottom" },
        bar: { groupWidth: 50 },
        fontSize: 12,
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            viewWindowMode: "explicit",
            viewWindow: { min: 0 }
        },
        hAxis: { },
        colors: [chart_color_scheme.blue, chart_color_scheme.brown]
    };

    someEvolutionChart.setVAxisMax(max_value, options);
    setHAxisFontSize(data, options);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(someEvolutionChart.container);
    chart.draw(data, options);
};


$(".reload-chart").click(function(){
    var item_header = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".dropdown-toggle");
    item_header.html($(this).text() + ' <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>');

    var interval = $(this).attr('data-interval');
    loadsomeEvolutionChart(interval);
});
```

The screen shots are explicity saying what are the problems. So, if you have ever passed through this problem, you're the dude that could help on this. I'll be greateful. Thanks in adavance!

Comment: Where did you get val.opportunity to calculate max value?

Comment: Data are pushed as `val.date, val.visited, val.calls`, max value is calculated from `val.visited, val.opportunity`?

Comment: What does `objects` look like in the callback for the 12-month chart?  What does it look like for the 6-month chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are creating different data sets for different intervals:

- if interval is 0, your data source is `url:
  /api/v1/.../?format=json&period__gte=2013-12`
- if interval is 6 your data source is `url: /api/v1/.../?format=json&period__gte=2013-6`
- if interval is 12 your data source is `url: /api/v1/.../?format=json&period__gte=2012-12`. Different year.

I build json file 'manually' and the charts produced with your code have the same data, so the problem is on the other side: what you are sending as a `objects` data.

See charts for interval of 12 and interval of 6 from 7-12. Numbers on x-axis should be months but I didn't want to spend to much time to get it all correct.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer gave me some hints of what and where might be the problem, not totally sure yet. I'll do some trails till find the center of the problem. Anyway, thanks by now Jurkovic.